# Is there a way to control spatial/memory locality when using Parallel.For

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a large array of unscaled floats - array length is 40,000,000.  In order to scale this array, I thought it would be more performant to use `Parallel.For()`.  Here's the sequential version of the for loop that scales the data:

```
for (i = 0; i < rawData.Length; i++)
{
    scaledData[i] = rawData[i] * scale + offset;
}
```

Here is that converted to use `Parallel.For()` e.g.:

```
Parallel.For(0, rawData.Length, i => {
    scaledData[i] = rawData[i] * scale + offset;
});
```

But the performance is worse! My guess, based on observing index/thread combinations, is that `Parallel.For()` is accessing memory in such a way as to cause excess paging.  To test this theory, I tried using `Parallel.Invoke()` like so:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => { for (int i =        0; i < 10000000; i++) { dst[i] = src[i] * scale + offset; } },
    () => { for (int i = 10000000; i < 20000000; i++) { dst[i] = src[i] * scale + offset; } },
    () => { for (int i = 20000000; i < 30000000; i++) { dst[i] = src[i] * scale + offset; } },
    () => { for (int i = 30000000; i < 40000000; i++) { dst[i] = src[i] * scale + offset; } },
);
```

And that performs noticeably better but I hate the hard-coded nature of this code.  I have 4 processors which is why there are 4 actions passed to Invoke().

Is there way to cajole `Parallel.For()` into distributing indices to threads in a fashion that doesn't thrash memory?

Comment: I think your actual problem is the overhead of invoking a delegate, since the code of a single iteration is so simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom partitioner to get the behavior you want without having to resort to using `Parallel.Invoke`. The `RangPartitioner` is what you want to start with.

```
    var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, rawData.Length);

    double[] results = new double[rawData.Length];

    Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, (range, loopState) =>
    {
        for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
        {
            scaledData[i] = rawData[i] * scale * offset;
        }
    });
```

You can create a custom partitioner and overload the [`GetPartition()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381767%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to adjust the block size to something that suites your needs.

See [Custom Partitioners for PLINQ and TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an in depth discussion.

Will this improve data locality, yes. Provided that your array contains value types. In which case they will be allocated as blocks of contiguous memory. For reference types this is not the case. FWIW I've tried to improve memory locality like this with OK but not astounding improvements. I came to the conclusion that there is potentially a lot of other memory access from the CLR and that this can make it hard to understand the resulting memory access patterns.

Comment: That seems to be about the same (or better) perf than my hard-coded hack.  Very nice!  Thanks.  I've been trying to combine data-parallelism with manual vectorization using the Microsoft.Bcl.Simd / RyuJIT CTPs.  It's been interesting to say the least.  :-)